# Why don't plus one oxidation state metals form stable complexes with hydroxide ion?

Tags: solubility

For example, why doesn't AgOH exist as a stable compound?

I read that it rapidly decomposes to silver oxide and water.

$\ce{2AgOH -> Ag2O + H2O}$ $~~~~~~~~~pK_{decomposition}= 2.875$

http://actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_14_p0717-0725.pdf

The above paper gives the pK value for the above equilibrium but doesn't bother to really delve into why silver hydroxide might be so unstable in water.

But why?

Is there repulsion between the silver cation and the proton?

Comment: Hard soft acid base theory says silver is soft and hydroxide is hard so they won't form a strong bond.

Comment: I know that but why exactly doesn't hard prefer hard?

Comment: It does.  The explanation I've seen is hard and hard bond ionically and soft and soft bond with more covalent character.

Comment: Oops I meant why doesn't hard prefer soft?

Comment: @BrinnBelyea but in Ag2O, Ag+ is soft and O2- is hard, but why do they form a bond?

Comment: They will form a bond but it isn't that strong.  In addition, one of the products of the reaction, water has a favorable enthalpy of formation.